# Team site landing page is in classic SharePoint - is there a way to move this page from classic to modern?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-team-site

I'm a SharePoint owner for a team site and inherited a classic landing page for this site. I want this landing page to be more dynamic with the awesome features only the modern style provides. Is there a way to permanently switch over from classic to modern?

Answer (score 0):

Except for a very few exceptions, Classic Team sites have the same features (or even more) as the Modern Team sites. This means classic Team Sites can:

- Have modern pages. Including modern home pages.
- Can be connected to a Microsoft 365 group
- Can be connected to a hub site.
- etc.

**Create a modern landing page for a classic site**

- Navigate to your classic Team Site
- Go to Site Contents
- New > Page

[image]

- Configure your mdoern page
- Save the modern page

[image]

- Navigate to the Site Pages library
- Right click on your new modern page
- Click Make homepage

[image]

- Done! Now your old classic team site has a modern landing page

**Note about converting pages**

You can't "convert" your classic page to a modern page. This is because the classic webparts are incompatible with the modern webparts. There are some scripts that can do this migration, but in your case it's faster to simply recreate the modern page manually.

Answer (score 0):

Transform to modern site pages using PowerShell:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-userinterface-site-pages-powershell

Sample blog for your reference:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/convert-classic-pages-to-modern-pages-using-pnp-powershell-script2